# Is Corona SDK 30 days only?

Tags: coronasdk

i'd like to know if Corona SDK is free and not limited by 30 days?

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: This question type is not appropriate for this forum.

Comment: so how do i delete it? i'm so sorry i coudn't find the answer anywhere so i came here, very sorry :(

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK is free for personal use. Essentially, you can use it for unlimited time for free, but only to develop and install on personal devices. To "Distribute to the iTunes App Store,
Android Marketplace, Amazon Kindle Fire Appstore, and Barnes & Noble NOOK Color Appstore." you have to purchase a license.

Check this for more information: http://www.anscamobile.com/pricing/whysubscribe.html?ref=corona